# Typescript bundling with Rollup and rollup-plugin-typescript2 gone bad

Tags: typescript, rollup

I'm trying to extract small part of monorepo to web client library and running into some unexpected hurdles, in here.
So, quite straight forward rollup config, like this:

```
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import sourceMaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';

export default {
    input: "../main.ts",
    output: {
        file: './bundle/rollup-bundle.js',
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'WebClient',
        sourcemap: true
    },
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        resolve({browser: true, mainFields: ['module']}),
        sourceMaps(),
    ]
};
```

Produces:

```sh
../main.ts → ./bundle/rollup-bundle.js...
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
..\main.ts (3:32)
1: [...]
2:
3: export const createClient = (url: string) => new ClientImpl([...]);
                                   ^
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

It just looks like `rollup-plugin-typescript2` doesn't do it's job of transpiling typescript and that just seems way too basic to not to work. I'm confused!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by `typescript2` and `node-resolve` being called in the wrong order:

> [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve] Must be before rollup-plugin-typescript2 in the plugin list, especially when `browser: true` option is used

(from `rollup-plugin-typescript2`'s [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2#rollup-plugin-node-resolve))

---

**Update**

The main issue turned out to be the positioning of some source files in higher folders with respect to the tsconfig root. By default tsconfig excluded them from the compilation:

> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the **containing directory and subdirectories**

([tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details))

Comment: Thanks for input. Although I've seen this line and it changes nothing as I just tried. 
I even removed mentions of source map to make setup even cleaner and still no luck.

Comment: And used massively. This code really is working fine in any other way. Anf `tsc` runs with no errors on this code base.

Comment: Just to be sure: `typescript` is installed locally, not globally right? Also, has the error message changed after swapping the two plugins?

Comment: Typescript was used from global scope. Just installed it locally as well and nothing changed. And yeah - error message stays the same all the time. It really looks like it stumbles upon first type declaration which is somehow never removed due to transpilation.

Comment: Typescript is reachable here. Just added `{verbose: 3}` (option I didn't know before) and I configuration of `rollup` and `typescript` which does not show any signs of potential problems to me.

Comment: Can I ask you to share the `tsconfig`?

Comment: And tsconfig:
```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208005/discussion-between-umbo-and-zii).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `rollup`is possibly built with idea, that it will be always located in project root, in mind. And once I attempted to place web client builder as a separate `app` in it's dedicated folder with it's dedicated tsconfig and rollup.config it all gone mad with no clear indications on why that was taking place.
Only obvious indication is that `rollup-plugin-typescript2` isn't capable to transpile (it's not even attempting to) any *.ts files located in higher folders and it took hell of a time to find this out.